# PayPalCoreSDK GetTransactionDetails has stopped returning a profile ID

Tags: c#, paypal

For some reason today my C# code that uses the latest version of the PayPalCoreSDK has stopped returning a profileID with the GetTransactionDetails() method. I have made no changes to our code whatsoever. We process hundreds of recurring subscriptions and without this ID our business is dead in the water.

Is anyone else witnessing this?

It looks like this same bug appeared in April but was fixed by PayPal:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647177/paypal-api-has-stopped-sending-profile-ids-any-way-to-match-payments-up-to-a-s

Answer (score 0):

Looks like PayPal has fixed this, our code has started working again.